# "crtdll.dll" in dependencies

Tags: dll, linker, crt, visual-studio-2010

The DLL I build with VC10 links CRT (as well as some other libs) statically. Suddenly I find that the most recent version of the DLL depends on "crtdll.dll" (while the previous version did not), and I'm trying to realize where this dependency comes from. Linker `/VERBOSE:LIB` switch didn't help: the only import library containing the word "crt" is `rpcrt4.lib`.

So, how can I find out why my DLL suddenly began depending on `crtdll.dll`?

Comment: This is not a standard DLL name.  The name of the import library doesn't necessarily match the DLL name.  Like msvcrt.lib vs msvcr100.dll.  You'll need to find the import library first, be sure you can account for all the .libs you see in the /verbose output.

Comment: @Hans Passant well, it doesn't match, but I'd expect it to *contain* the substring "crt"... As for full "verbose" output - it's too big. How to redirect it to a file in MSVC10?

Comment: @Igor R.: When I had to analyze the verbose linker output I just let the linker finish, then went to "output" window and used "Ctrl-A", then "Ctrl-C", then pasted the text into a suitable text editor.

Comment: @sharptooth In my case the output window contains only ~10% of the most recent output lines :)